# Save spinner state even moved to another activity with Android

Tags: android, spinner, state

I want to save my spinner state even when I move to a different activity and come back to the page with the spinner, the state should be the same. I have no idea how to do it, I saw some examples on other threads on stack overflow but I don't understand them.

Here's my code:

```
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
           // storing string resources into Array
            lang_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_list);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected : " + lang_list[index], 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            choice =  spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            // edit_cate.setText(choice);

            final ImageView country_flag = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.country);
            String s=((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
            if(s.equals("English"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eng_spinner));
            if(s.equals("German"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.german_spinner));
            if(s.equals("French"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.french_spinner));
            if(s.equals("Spanish"))
                country_flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spanish_spinner));
        }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save state of your spinner so this would be helpful to you.

1.) Apply this after creating spinner object

```
spinner.setSelection(getPersistedItem());
```

2.) Create these methods according to you to save the state of your spinner selected item

```
private int getPersistedItem() { 
String keyName = makePersistedItemKeyName();
 return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(keyName, 0); 
} 
protected void setPersistedItem(int position) {
 String keyName = makePersistedItemKeyName();
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt(keyName, position).commit();
 } 
private String makePersistedItemKeyName() {
 return currentUserName + "_your_key"; 
}
```

3.) Set its state as the spinner selection changed:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 
@Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position, long itemId) { 
setPersistedItem(position);
 } @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 } });
```

Comment: can you explain what is this? return currentUserName + "_your_key";  I don't understand what I have to return and no.3 how would I set the state, I try putting setPersistedItem(position); in my method but it gives an error.